# Unbalance voltage mesurements from 63 kV power transformer

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, circuits

After testing a power transformer(pt) and closing its wiring terminals I've encountered that phase S 63 kV correct voltage and phases R and T shows incorrect voltage 32 kV.

Can any body tell why?

Comment: is there any load on the phases?

Comment: So how does that tell us if there is any load?

Comment: This pt is in the switchyard and between Gen and line.When we have tried to connect the line (Gen is disconnected)to the switchgear the protection operated with the above voltages that pt read.(line voltage)

Comment: I suggest you get a qualified electrician to look into what is going on and don't touch any more.

Comment: There is no load on it. Just voltage

Comment: So you are deleting your previous comments

Comment: What do you mean by 'closing  its wiring terminals ' ? Are you trying yo find the short circuit properties? Sorry but the question is really vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I Know when you close the breaker you have seen the  voltages.
You should check the secondary circuits fuses.
This voltages shows open circuits of one poles.
If the polarity of poles were incorrect you shoud have seen 37Kv on other poles.
If fuses were healthy you shoud check the open circuits of PT secondery circuits.